# Melhor jeito de um bean chamar um outro bean passando ele mesmo como parametro em JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Eu tenho uma relação 1:n, onde um Sistema pode ter vários Loggers.
Tenho também dois beans: um para Sistema (SistemaBean que se refere a página sistemas.xhtml) e outro para Logger (LoggerBean que se refere a página loggers.xhtml). 
Na pagina sistemas.xhtml para cada sistema exibido em um datatable, tem um botão que quando clicado, deve ir para a página loggers.xhtml e mostrar todos os loggers daquele sistema.
Eu não sei muito bem JSF, então o que eu faço é o seguinte (embora não saiba se é o jeito certo de se fazer). Quando o usuário clica no sistema para ver quais são os logger dele, eu chamo uma função que guarda na sessão o sistema que foi escolhido e em seguida eu redireciono a nevegação para a página loggers.xhtml.
 Assim:

```
public void vaiPraLoggers(Sistema sistema) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("sistema", sistema);

    NavigationHandler handler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    handler.handleNavigation(context, null,"/pages/alert/alert-loggers?faces-redirect=true" );
    context.renderResponse(); 
}
```

Até ai, tá funcionando certo, ele tá redirecionando.

O problema é que na página loggers.xhtml há , além da datatable que exibe todos os loggers do sistema um botão para adicionar um novo logger. Qundo esse botão é clicado, ele deve setar como o sistema do logger o sistema que foi gravado na sessão que foi carregado pelo @PostConstructor do LoggerBean.
Assim:

```
@PostConstruct
private void initialize(Sistema sistema) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    this.usuarioLogado = (Usuario) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("usuarioLogado");
    this.sistema = (Sistema) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("sistema");
    this.logger = new Logger();
    this.loggerDao = new LoggerDAO();
```

E método que deveria salvar:

```
public void novoLogger() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    msgTela = verificaRequisitosLogger();
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(msgTela)) {
            logger.setSistema(this.sistema);
            this.loggerDao.salvar(logger, usuarioLogado);

            this.listaLoggers.add(logger);

            this.msgTela = Autenticador.getLocale().getString("sucessoLoggerSalvo");
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "", msgTela));    
    }else {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", msgTela));
    }
}
```

O que acontece é que no método que salva o logger, o sistema está como nulo. Parece que ele não chama o @PostConstruct.

Todos os meus escopos são @ViewScoped, não sei se é isso que está interferindo.
Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo errado, ou a melhor forma de fazer o que eu quero?

obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Nas implementações utilizando JSF eu não costumo passar o objeto inteiro para a página seguinte. O que normalmente eu faço é passar o id para a página destino, e nesta eu faço uma consulta carregando o objeto por completo. Por exemplo:

**Pagina de consulta**

```
                    <p:column headerText="Título"
                              filterBy="#{tarefa.titulo}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                              sortBy="#{tarefa.titulo}">
                        <h:link value="#{tarefa.titulo}" outcome="cadastro-tarefa.xhtml">
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{tarefa.id}"/>
                        </h:link>
                    </p:column>
```

**Página destino**

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{cadastroTarefaMB.idTarefa}" converter="javax.faces.Long"/>
    <f:event listener="#{cadastroTarefaMB.inicializar()}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
</f:metadata>
```

**CadastroTarefaMB**

```
    public void inicializar() {
    if (idTarefa != null) {
        tarefa = tarefaService.porId(idTarefa);
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANTE**

Se fosse passar o objeto inteiro para a página seguinte, certamente você terá que carregá-lo por completo neste página. Tornando uma consulta desnecessário, podendo influenciar no desempenho do sistema.

**Código Fonte**
https://github.com/karanalpe/crud-adminfaces